# Observer Uml & Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

I really need your help for a question: the right implementation of pattern Observer. The fact is that I have no guarantees about doing right so I just would like to know if there are inconsistencies between UML and code below, please report me any minimum mistake/improvable detail in both parties. I would be so much grateful to anyone, thanks in advance.

UML:

[image: Observer UML]

JAVA CODE:

```
public interface Subject {
    public void registerObserver(Observer o);
    public void removeObserver(Observer o);
    public void notifyObservers();
}

public class ConcreteSubject implements Subject {
    private int my_state;
    private ArrayList<Observer> observers;
    public ConcreteSubject(){
        observers=new ArrayList<Observer>();
    }
    public void registerObserver(Observer o){
        observers.add(o);
    }
    public void removeObserver(Observer o){
        observers.remove(o);
    }
    public void notifyObservers(){
        for(Observer o : observers)
            o.update();
    }
    //PULL Mode -> Observer musts grab the state of the subject
    public int getState(){
       return my_state;
    }
    public void setState(int state){
        my_state=state;
    }
 }

public interface Observer {
    public void update(); //In PULL mode update don't need the state of the subject in argument
}

public class ConcreteObserver implements Observer {
    private ConcreteSubject my_subject;
    public ConcreteObserver(ConcreteSubject subject){
        my_subject=subject;
    }
    public void update(){
        System.out.println("The state is: "+my_subject.getState());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to implement ***Subject*** as abstract class, so ***ConcreteSubject*** will care only about change of the state and notification of the observers.
With this approach you can have more ***ConcreteSubjects***.
Check example of the [Observer pattern](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Observer/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your idea is of course good but in this way ConcreteSubjects couldn't extend anything else. I'd like to implement in Java that kind of diagram and just would like to know if there are inconsistencies. For example: cardinality between interfaces and concrete classes is different and I'm not sure it is right. More, is it correct to implement the association between concrete classes with the subject attribute since I want to do it in PULL mode? (in PUSH mode I just would have to add the state in the update call, isn't it?)